# Get querystring value from URL inside larger string with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, regex, preg-match

I have this html string, that contains a very specific url that I need to grab.

```
$string = 'Hi, this is a long string,
<br>
some more text, and then suddenly, a script tag!
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/static/123456/js/SiteCatalyst.js"></script>
<p>more text here</p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/other.js"></script>
and then, the end...';
```

The catch is, I need the **123456** value, which happens to be inside this string;

> http://www.example.com/static/xxxxxx/js/SpecificScript.js

Since that value can (and will) change in the string, it needs to be parsed dinamically. My first approach was to find all urls inside the string, but that can be too expensive if there are many urls.

**TL;DR**: How can I get the **xxxxxx** value that is inside a url, which is inside a larger html string?

Comment: does it always exists in the src attribute? is `http://www.example.com/static/` a static part?

Comment: @AvinashRaj yes, it will always be inside a script tag.

Comment: see this link http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm, you can load the text to the Simple HTML DOM Parser. and access the <script> tag and you can separate what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\K` to ignore the previously matched characters from printing at the final.

```
src="http://www.example.com/static/\K\d+(?=\/)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aZ6zX0/6)

```
$string = 'Hi, this is a long string,
<br>
some more text, and then suddenly, a script tag!
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/static/123456/js/SiteCatalyst.js"></script>
<p>more text here</p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/other.js"></script>
and then, the end...';
preg_match('~src="http://www.example.com/static/\K\d+(?=\/)~', $string, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

Output:

```
123456
```

Answer (score 1):

```
http:\/\/www\.example\.com\/static\/(\d+)\/js
```

Try this.Grab the capture.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nL5yL3/1

Comment: It is kind of working. Instead of just returning `$match[0] = 123456` it is returning 2 items in the array, where the first one is the complete url (unnecessary). Any ideas why?

Comment: @andufo `match[0] return the match string always.`use `match[1]` to get the correct group

Answer (score 0):

Using  look arounds

```
(?<=http:\/\/www.example.com\/static\/)\d+(?=\/js)
```

[**Regex Example**](https://regex101.com/r/vU4kF1/1)

Comment: *Get querystring value from URL inside larger string with PHP* Javascript does not support lookbehind. But OP wants PHP

Answer (score 0):

You can use php `preg_match_all()` and get a number

```
$string = 'Hi, this is a long string,
<br>
some more text, and then suddenly, a script tag!
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/static/123456/js/SiteCatalyst.js"></script>
<p>more text here</p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/other.js"></script>
and then, the end...';

preg_match_all('!\d+!', $string, $matches);
echo $matches[0][0]; //output 123456
```

Comment: That would get all numbers, and not just the one i'm looking for.